# Changing order of addition changes result

Tags: node.js, algorithm, math

Changing the order of addition in line 11 of the program gives to different answers.

```js
function gcf(a,b){
  if(a%b === 0)
    return b;
  else 
    return gcf(b,a%b);
}

let x = {num: 3, den: 2};
let n = 1000;
let ans = 0;
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
  let num = x.den + x.num + x.den  ;
  let den = x.num + x.den;
  let g = gcf(num, den);
  num /= g;
  den /= g;
  x = {
    num: num,
    den: den
  }
  // console.log(i+2,x,x.num.toString().length > x.den.toString().length, x.num/x.den, g);
  if(x.num.toString().length > x.den.toString().length){
    ans+=1
  }
}
console.log(ans);
```

```js
function gcf(a,b){
  if(a%b === 0)
    return b;
  else 
    return gcf(b,a%b);
}

let x = {num: 3, den: 2};
let n = 1000;
let ans = 0;
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
  let num = x.den + x.den + x.num;
  let den = x.num + x.den;
  let g = gcf(num, den);
  num /= g;
  den /= g;
  x = {
    num: num,
    den: den
  }
  // console.log(i+2,x,x.num.toString().length > x.den.toString().length, x.num/x.den, g);
  if(x.num.toString().length > x.den.toString().length){
    ans+=1
  }
}
console.log(ans);
```

This gives 189

```
let num = x.den + x.num + x.den;
```

This gives 158

```
let num = x.den + x.den + x.num;
```

What is happening?

**
Solving to get how many fractional approximation of root 2 has denominatior digits less than numerator digits.

Comment: Summing some of the numbers results in a new number that is greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. This naturally leads to unsafe operations later on, so if `a + b > MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` then `a + b + c` is not necessarily equivalent to `a + c + b`.

Comment: You can circumvent this by using the new [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) data type (if supported).